# Is necessary to use iframe tag in gwt host?

Tags: java, gwt

What is the use of having iframe tag in gwt host html page? Is any specific reasons behind this?

**When i'm using iframe with ssl enabled it's giving me an popup window(get messages stating that there is un-secure content in the page.). Happening only in ie.. How to avoid this ?**

**Update**: the problem was because of the Flash used in the page (FlasTag setting the code base to http://download.macromedia.com). More details [here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/09/17/even-more-problems-with-the-ie-8-mixed-content-warning/#comment-36101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__gwt_historyFrame is used to store/retrive [history tokens](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) (make back/forward button work correctly). If you don't embed an iframe, GWT history mechanism won't work.

Update by [Tomas Broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer):

> This is only true for IE6 and IE7. IE8 will use onhashchange, and
>   other browsers do not need the iframe either (using a timer to
>   regularly check the location's hash)

As pointent out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286517/gwt-application-generating-ie-insecure-item-warning), iframe is not the only possible cause.

Comment: Note this is only true for IE6 and IE7. IE8 will use onhashchange, and other browsers do not need the iframe either (using a timer to regularly check the location's hash)

Comment: When i'm using iframe with ssl enabled it's giving me an popup window(get messages stating that there is un-secure content in the page.). Happening only in ie.. How to avoid this ??

Comment: which iframe? :) history? when you remove the frame (and that's the only change you make) than you don't get the 'unsecure content' warning? As pointent out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286517/gwt-application-generating-ie-insecure-item-warning iframe is not the only possible cause.

Comment: good, can you provide some details so that others facing the same problem can easily find the solution?

Comment: The problem is happened because of the Flash we used in the page. http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/09/17/even-more-problems-with-the-ie-8-mixed-content-warning/ Check out this link and comment no 15.